# Расширение массива в cpp

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Возможно ли реализовать реализовать именно расширение памяти? Или хотя бы при помощи манипуляций с указателями избежать лишнего копирования данных? Сейчас использую следующий алгоритм:

1. Выделить память под новый объект
2. Поэлементно скопировать данные
3. Удалить указатель на изначальную версию массива
4. Присвоить указатель на новый массив изначальному указателю

```
CountTarget++;
TTarget** nTargets = new TTarget* [CountTarget];
    
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < CountTarget-1; i++)
  nTargets[i] = Targets[i];
delete[] Targets;
    
Targets = nTargets;
```

Comment: Лучше, чем в стандартной библиотеке вряд ли получится. Просто выделяйте больше памяти, чтобы не проделывать это всё при каждом добавлении элемента в массив.

Comment: Дело в том, что я пишу задание в универе, а не прогу для применения)) Но решил зайти чуть дальше

Comment: Используйте [malloc/realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)